# chart.js issue with display between two charts with same code

Tags: chart.js

I'm having an issue with data vertically too close together in the first chart while the other is not.

[Chart With Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMtQ.png)

[Chart Without Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7nEu.png)

[Transition between charts (scroll down halfway)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6PS3.png)

Actual Chart to view: http://www.ironclads.com/temp/chart.html

As you can see from the images the text and corresponding chart values are compressed together in the first chart but look ok in the second.

The code is the same and the values in the first chart are 1000, while the second chart is 703. Is this why it compresses the first chart values? If so, is there anything I can do programmatically to resolve the issue between charts or am I on the right track that I just need to get the entry count closer to the same in order for the two charts to look the same?

I'm attaching the code to the html chart file in question as a link below. I also try to limit the number of entries to 1000 or less per chart in order for them to not break the browser or the chart.

Any ideas you have or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

http://www.ironclads.com/temp/chart.html

Comment: Why are people deprecating my question?  I'm asking a legit question.  Just because you don't know an answer to my question, doesn't mean you deprecate it.  If you don't understand, you are welcome to ask.  I'm happy to add any details you feel are missing and I appreciate any input you can provide.

Comment: When you [asked the same question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75012158/3775731) it was closed due to a lack of debugging details. This question will most likely be closed for the same reason. To avoid that please carefully read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I suggest you also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it is reproduceable following my instructions.  I don't have any other debugging information to provide.  I've tried tweaking the code, but everything I do effects things adversely.  I guess I'll attempt to make sure each chart has the same number of elements.  Because that's the only thing that works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok folks. Figured it out with some help elsewhere.  It appears a sub wrapper is in order, along with changing that subwrappper to fit.  Here's the link to the fixed chart, you can compare the first with this and see the changes.

http://www.ironclads.com/temp/chart_fixed.html